# Creating an AMI from an EC2 instance with mounted volumes

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, amazon-ami

I have an EBS-backed instance with a 2nd mounted volume (I followed the steps in [Eric's Article](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1663))

I then created an AMI from that instance, and ran an instance from that AMI.

That 2nd instance then created two volumes.

Is there a way to control how the volumes associated with with an AMI are created, or is the solution just to unmount the 2nd volume before creating the AMI?

Comment: How did you create the AMI from the instance? AWS console? ec2-create-image command line?

Comment: Command line: ec2-create-image <instance id>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ec2-create-image` command line tool has a `--block-device-mapping` option to define the volumes associated with new instances.

> http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-CreateImage.html

In your specific case, you may want to suppress the automatic creation and attaching of the database volume by specifying something like:

```
ec2-create-image --block-device-mapping /dev/sdh=none [...]
```

This will let you create and attach your own volumes to the new instances.

Alternatively, you could specify that an empty volume be created an attached when a new instance is started:

```
ec2-create-image --block-device-mapping /dev/sdh=:20:false [...]
```

When you run an instance, you could override the size of that volume using the `--block-device-mapping` option to `ec2-run-instances`.

It's also worth learning about the `delete-on-termination` flag for `--block-device-mapping` so that you understand how to control whether your second volume should automatically be deleted when the instance is terminated.